# how can we place our files in document root? (copy-paste not working)

Tags: 20.04, apache2

My Apache Web server is working and I need to copy some files to document root.

Comment: What is "document root"? Is it `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Ok my problem is solved. My real problem was a problem with permissions and I solved it using the commands ls -l and chmod.